# Split path in Python

Tags: python, path, split

How I could split this:

```
C:\my_dir\repo\branch
```

to:

```
['C:\my_dir', rest_part_of_string]
```

where `rest_part_of_string` can be one string or could be splitted every `\`. I don't care about rest, i just want first two elements together.

Comment: use  raw strings?? r"C:\my_dir\repo\branch"

[link](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) ([`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)):

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.match(r'[^\\]+\\[^\\]+', r'C:\my_dir\repo\branch').group())
C:\my_dir

>>> re.findall(r'[^\\]+\\[^\\]+|.+', r'C:\my_dir\repo\branch')
['C:\\my_dir', '\\repo\\branch']
```

Comment: @MateuszSzymański, Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are people who have tried to answer your question. If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) that was most useful for you.

Comment: Yeah, but i have to wait about 1 hour before i can do it. And yesterday i had no access to SO. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

python 3.4 has methods for that (note the forward slashes instead of the backslashes (or double the backslashes))

[pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths)

```
# python 3.4
from pathlib import Path

p  = Path('C:/my_dir/repo/branch')

print(p.parent)
print(p.name)
```

for what you need `parts` is interesting:

```
print(p.parts)
# -> ('C:', 'my_dir', 'repo', 'branch')
print('\\'.join(p.parts[:2]), ' -- ', '\\'.join( p.parts[2:])) 
# -> C:\my_dir  --  repo\branch
```

in python 2.7 this needs a bit more work:

```
import os

p = 'C:/my_dir/repo/branch'

def split_path(path):
    parts = []
    while 1:
        path, folder = os.path.split(path)
        if folder:
            parts.append(folder)
        else:
            if path:
                parts.append(path)
            break
    parts.reverse()
    return parts

parts = split_path(p)
print('\\'.join(parts[:2]), ' -- ', '\\'.join(parts[2:]))
# -> C:\my_dir  --  repo\branch
```

Comment: pathlib has been backported to Python 2 as [pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/)

Answer (score 0):

you could split the path on `\` and rejoin based on index:

```
>>>my_path = r'C:\my_dir\repo\branch'
>>>split_path = ["\\".join(my_path.split("\\")[:2]), "\\".join(my_path.split("\\")[2:])]
['C:\\my_dir', 'repo\\branch']

>>> first, last = "\\".join(x.split("\\")[:2]), "\\".join(x.split("\\")[2:])
>>> print first, last
C:\my_dir repo\branch
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) (or `os.path.split`), applied recursively or iteratively, until you cannot go up in the directory hierarchy further.

In general the functions provided by `os.path` should work better that re-invented wheels, due to better cross-platform support.  There are a large number of primitives from which you can build your own path-manipulating function.